# Tools for a data science job

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, apache-spark, sql, tableau

Could someone list out all the important tools and software required for a data science job? Example spark, tensorflow, SQL, tableau etc.

It would be helpful if you could list the domain and then 2 tools.

Comment: This question seems subjective and preference-based: there are many important tools, people using R may use totally different tools than Python people or Scala (Spark) people, there are dozens of subareas with specific tools (recommendation systems, geospatial,...). Therefore, this question may not be a good fit to this site according to the [site guidelines](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: this is just an example and not specific to any field, but it comes from a personel experience:

 - scikit-learn for Classical Machine Learning.
 - Tensorflox for Deep Learning.
 - RL-Glue for reinforcement-learning.
 - Power-BI for reporting and visualization.
 - SQL Server Integration Services for ETL.
 - SQL Server Analysis Services for OLAP cubes.
 - Apache Spark for a large data processing.
 - MLFlow for your end-to-end machine learning lifecycle.
 - Cloud services provider for hosting your project

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is not clear enough. You need to be exact about the job description. But I have a suggestion for you to figure this out on your own.

Simply go to LinkedIn, look for the jobs you are considering (read their descriptions and responsibilities carefully). These job postings mostly come up with a list of the required experiences. This will give you an idea of the type of jobs out there and what they are expecting from the candidates.